# how to add up and down scrolling key arrow in div Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

how can i add up and down keyboard functionality in a div while typing in textarea. Anyone?
[image]

in this pic, you can see when i write anything after @, the div gets open, i want to add up/down keyboard functionality in this without using any library.

few codes.

```
const [textAreaInput, setTextAreaInput] = useState("");
const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

function changes(event) {
// console.log(event.target.value);
setTextAreaInput(event.target.value)



if (event.target.value.indexOf("@") != -1) {
  handle_mf_Result(event.target.value.substring(event.target.value.indexOf("@") + 1, event.target.value.length));
}
else setShow(false)

}


return 
<>
  { show ? <div class="chatbot_list" >{lists_of_fund}</div> : null}
  

  <textarea
    ref={input => input && input.focus()}
    id="chatbot_btn-input"
    type="text"
    className="chatbot_comments-textarea"
    placeholder="Type something... or use @ to search"
    value={textAreaInput}
    onChange={changes}
  />
```

Comment: that will be complete custom autosuggest functionality you will have to create according to your logic.

Comment: i have already created this div, which suggest only when i write @ and some text after that, till this its fine, now i want to add one more feature, suppose it it pops up the suggestion, then i want to use the keyboard up and down to scroll up and down from that pop up div. so, that it what i want to ask, how can i do it? any logic for it!

Comment: i understood the question you want the focused functionality for the suggestion just like other autosuggest gives you, that's what i am suggesting to create your own logic taking help from the autosuggest libraries for the keyboard events and mouse events used in the libraries.